# ActiveRecordIntegration to support IStatelessSession

Tags: castle-activerecord

it seems that AR Integration doesn't support to open StatelessSession, from looking at:
http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Facilities.ActiveRecordIntegration/blob/master/src/Castle.Facilities.ActiveRecordIntegration/SessionFactoryDelegate.cs

looking at line 62, if you don't call OpenSession it will throw exception.
I would like to call OpenStatelessSession to initialize IStatelessSession.

I saw that some people are talking about StatelessSessionScope but I didn't manage to find good examples for using it with AR Integration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, it's not currently implemented/supported. Please file an issue in the [issue tracker](http://issues.castleproject.org) and if possible also fork and implement it :-)